# How to React Context api typescript setting?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am changing the app.js file to app.tsx.

Currently, the value has the following error.

```
app.tsx

import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";
import SelectPage from "./pages/select/select";
import ResultPage from "./pages/result/result";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

export const GlobalContext = createContext(null);

function App() {
  const [checkCrypto, setCheckCrypto] = useState([]);
  const [start, setStart] = useState(false);

  const value = {
    checkCrypto,
    setCheckCrypto,
    start,
    setStart,
  };

  return (
    <>
      <GlobalContext.Provider value={value}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<SelectPage />} />
          <Route path="/result" element={<ResultPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </GlobalContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image]

As I changed it like the code below, it was solved, but I want to find another way.

```
export const GlobalContext:any = createContext(null);
```

What type should I apply to solve the problem?

Comment: https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react#context

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this.

```
interface AppContextInterface {
  checkCrypto: number[];
  start: boolean;
}

export const GlobalContext = createContext<AppContextInterface | null>(null);

function App() {
  const [checkCrypto, setCheckCrypto] = useState([]);
  const [start, setStart] = useState(false);

  const value = {
    checkCrypto,
    setCheckCrypto,
    start,
    setStart,
  };

  return (
    <>
      <GlobalContext.Provider value={value}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<SelectPage />} />
          <Route path="/result" element={<ResultPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </GlobalContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you've shown, this should work.

If you visit the TypeScript playground link and hover over `value` on line 14, you can see the type that you need to use as the generic for `createContext`.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=3&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=5#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)

```ts
export const GlobalContext = createContext<{
  checkCrypto: number[];
  setCheckCrypto: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number[]>>;
  start: boolean;
  setStart: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}>(undefined as any);

function App() {
  const [checkCrypto, setCheckCrypto] = useState<number[]>([]);
  const [start, setStart] = useState(false);

  const value = {
    checkCrypto,
    setCheckCrypto,
    start,
    setStart,
  };

// ...
```